# Can't seem to render a page through express

Tags: javascript, express

I'm trying to render an html page with express. Here's what I have so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on PORT 3000');
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Home page!')
})

app.get('/events', function(req, res){
  res.render('eventForm')
})
```

my file tree so far:

```
-Project
-node_modules
-public
    index.html
-views
    eventForm.html
```

I tried putting the eventForm.html in `public` as well but for some reason my server can't "find" it. I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "eventForm" in views directory "/Users/username/LearnProgramming/api_playground/stubhub/views"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your views before setting view engine

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Comment: So I tried that, and I imported `path` as well. It's still giving me the same error for some reason...

`Error: Failed to lookup view "eventForm" in views directory "/Users/carlosgrijalva/LearnProgramming/api_playground/stubhub/views"`

Comment: Change your eventForm,html to eventForm.ejs Ejs has its own extension

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on PORT 3000');
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Home page!')
})

app.get('/events', function(req, res){
  res.render('eventForm')
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: This worked as well, do I usually have to set my static files at the end or something?

Comment: Yes you do have to set it that way.

Answer (score 0):

How about eventForm with **.html**?